# Storyboards multiple buttons cause same segue

Tags: iphone, ios, uistoryboard, segue

I'm working on trying to figure out storyboards and it all seems pretty cool but I'm having problems with moving from one screen with a few buttons to another screen no matter which button is pressed. Obviously I can control drag from each button but then I have segues all over the place on the story board and I feel like there has to be a better way to do it. I've tried highlighting all the buttons and control-dragging to the next screen but that only caused the one I dragged from to work.

Here's an illustration of what I have that works right now...

[image: This works but it's hideous!!!]

If I have to stick with this then so be it but I'm going to end up with 6 buttons on one page and 8 on another. That's alot of segues. Basically each button signifies a choice for the user. That choice will cause different things to happen behind the scenes but no matter which button they choose they move to the next screen.

**What I've Tried:**

- Highlighting all the buttons and then dragging to the next view controller.

  - This failed because it only connected the segue to the button I clicked on when I control-dragged
- Dragging out one segue then dragging from the second button to the circle part of the segue.

  - This caused nothing at all to happen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm unaware of a way to give a single segue multiple triggers in a storyboard, however you could create a single segue with a particular identifier, and then have all of the buttons respond to a single `IBAction` that calls `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:...]`;

Comment: Interesting as I need ibactions for all the buttons anyway. Doing it this way would I drag from view control to view controller to make the segue instead of from the button to the view controller?

Comment: @CaldwellYSR Correct, you just drag from one to the other, set the segue type,a nd give it an identifier

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Another noobish question how do I select a segue so I can see it's identifier? In case I forget what I put it to.

Comment: @CaldwellYSR Either click on the line leading from the one view to the other, or the bubble.  You can also See the segue in your Objects inspector on the left hand side of the screen under the source view controller's scene

Comment: Perfect! I tried that before I asked you but it didn't work. Must have missed it or something.

Comment: you could also have only one IBAction that connects to all the buttons and then simply identify the button that was pressed and perform its actions

Answer (score 3):

Check out generic segues, which are tied to the source view controller instead of an IBAction:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8868096/295130