# Segue from UITableViewCell to another ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a created an `Single view application` with storyboard, I dragged and dropped a `TableView` . I am able to inflate the tableview and get some data but on clicking any of the `UITableViewCell` I need to goto the next `ViewController`. I dragged and dropped another `ViewController` to the storyboard and connected the `MainViewController` to the newly created `ViewController`. I need to goto the new View controller from the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

I tried using this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
TestViewController *test = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Testing"];
[test performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Test" sender:self];
}
```

I am getting this error

> 2013-09-03 23:33:21.234 Storyboard[946:c07] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard
>   () doesn't contain a view controller with
>   identifier 'Testing''
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1c92012 0x10cfe7e 0x45b679 0x2f14 0xc3285 0xc34ed 0xacd5b3 0x1c51376 0x1c50e06 0x1c38a82 0x1c37f44
>   0x1c37e1b 0x1bec7e3 0x1bec668 0x13ffc 0x28ed 0x2815) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminate called throwing an exception

I also tried

```
[test performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Test" sender:self];
```

But i am not able to find a proper code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell us what's happening.  Is it crashing?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: You may find this answer useful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809833/xcode-4-2-ios5-multiple-segue-from-a-uitableview/8868096#8868096

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your table view is performing the segue, not the control you want to segue too.  You probably want it to say:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Test" sender:self];
```

Also make sure your Segue has the proper ID:

[image]

Comment: @user2735210 I don't believe it's possible to set it's ID programically

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an ID for the view you want to push to.  You need to go into the storyboard choose your view and set the Storyboard ID to `Testing`

[image]

Comment: @user2735210 I don't believe it's possible to set it's ID programically

Comment: Also in Attributes inspector when i click the segue I get Identifier? So what is that identifier and Storyboard ID ?

Comment: The `Segue Identifier` is like `Storyboard ID` except it's for Segues only.  It defines a specific segue or method of switching views.  The `Storyboard ID` is a unique identifier for a storyboard.